# Set Theory intersection and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $B_n = [0, 1 + n^{−1} ),\space\space T_n = [0, 1 − n^{−1} ],\space\space n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Show that $\bigcap B_n = [0, 1]$ and $\bigcup T_n = [0, 1)$

Sadly, I don't understand the problem enough to be able to prove the conjecture. Any ideas what I should apply to show it? Thank you!

Comment: To show set equality, show containment both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x \in [0,1]$. Then $0 \leq x \leq 1 < 1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $x \in B_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and

$$ x \in \cap B_n$$

Therefore

$$[0,1] \subseteq \cap B_n$$

Suppose $x \in \cap B_n$. Then for $n \geq 1$, we have $0 \leq x < 1+\frac{1}{n}$. Assume on the contrary $x = 1 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$ and

$$ x = 1 + \epsilon > 1 + \frac{1}{N} $$

Therefore $x \in B_N^c$. We arrive at a contradiction. We have $x \leq 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

We obtain the other side

$$\cap B_n \subseteq [0,1]$$

The other statement is just an analogue.